# Writing barrier with shared memory in C

Tags: c, linux, synchronization, shared-memory

I need to write barrier for process synchronisation. I did and it was working until I put struct barrier in shared memory. My code is as follows:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>



void nanosleep2(long t)
{
    struct timespec a;
    a.tv_sec = 0;
    a.tv_nsec = t;
    nanosleep(&a, NULL);
}






struct barrier
{
    int n;  // number of processes
    sem_t mutex;

    int count;
    sem_t bar;
};


void init(struct barrier * b, int n)
{
    b->n = n;
    b->count = 0;
    sem_init(&b->mutex, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&b->bar, 0, 0);
}


void destroy(struct barrier * b)
{
    sem_destroy(&b->mutex);
    sem_destroy(&b->bar);
}

void wait(struct barrier * b)
{
    sem_wait(&b->mutex);  // It seems that some processes never get acces to mutex, but isn't it impossible?

    ++(b->count);
    printf("Horse is there!, %d/%d\n", b->count, b->n);

    if (b->count == b->n)
    {
        printf("the barierr is open!\n");

        sem_post(&b->bar);
    }

    sem_post(&b->mutex);

    sem_wait(&b->bar);
    sem_post(&b->bar);
}


struct barrier * barr_open(const char * name)
{
    int fd = shm_open(name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
    ftruncate(fd, sizeof(struct barrier));
    struct barrier * res = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct barrier), PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    close(fd);
    return res;
}


void barr_close(struct barrier * barr, const char * name)  // if name is not NULL, it also unlinks
{
    munmap(barr, sizeof(struct barrier));

    if (name != NULL)
        shm_unlink(name);
}





const int N = 5;  // number of horses

void * horse(void * _)
{
    struct barrier * barr = barr_open("/barieraa");

    nanosleep2((rand()%200)+10);
    wait(barr);

    barr_close(barr, NULL);

    return NULL;
}



int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    struct barrier * barr = barr_open("/barieraa");

    init(barr, N);

    sleep(1);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        pthread_t t;
        pthread_create(&t, NULL, horse, NULL);
        pthread_detach(t);

        nanosleep2(rand()%200);
    }

    sleep(1);
    destroy(barr);
    barr_close(barr, "/barieraa");

    return 0;
}
```

So, the first printf in wait() only three or four horses are able to reach. Probably something grabs mutex and doesn't return, but is it possible? Why barrier itself works, shared memory itself works, but they both together don't want?

Comment: You need to use [`sem_init(&b->mutex, 1, n)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html) for it to work in shared memory and for calls to [`sem_wait(&b->bar)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html) to block until there are `n` waiters. Also, remember that [semaphores](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) are not [mutexes](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock). Both are used for synchronization, but they work in different ways.

Comment: Also remember that `sem_wait()` has a return code, and don't always succeed (it can be interrupted, for instance).  Therefore in `wait()` there are no guarantees that you actually acquired the semaphore before modifying variables in shared memory.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thanks, it's working! I only needed to change every sem_init(x, 0, y) to  sem_init(x, 1, y).